# How to create a method able for use everywhere in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-helper

I want to make some changes to dates, for example, I want to explode it do some operation and implode it again, and I want to use it all around my app so here is my code :

```php
$divided_date = explode('/', $request->point_date);
$converted_date = Verta::getGregorian($divided_date[0], $divided_date[1], $divided_date[2]); // [2015,12,25]
$begindate = implode('/', $converted_date);
```

I want to make a function called DateConvertor() for example, and anywhere that I want to convert the date I use something like below.

```
$request->somedate()->DateConvertor();
```

or for example

```
Dateconvertor($request->someday);
```

And it returns the converted date so now I don't know to use the static method or no, and I don't know where to define it so I can use it in all of my app not just a single model.

Comment: You can find instructions here: https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Comment: try traits in laravel.

Comment: The link given by @Thomas is all you need, if you need something available everywhere, the helper is your best choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Helper.php` file and in `composer.json` include that file as

```
"files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php",   
]
```

**or** may add a helper class like

```
<?php


namespace App\Helpers;


class Helper
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

and `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [

    ....

    'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,

]
```

and then use as `Helper::foo();`

**or** add a service provider like

```
php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider
```

in register method

```
public function register()
{
    require_once app_path() . '/Helpers/Custom/Helper.php';
}
```

In `config/app.php`

`providers = 
[
'CustomHelper' => App\Helpers\Custom\Helper::class,
]`

and

```
'aliases' => [
'CustomHelper' => App\Helpers\Custom\User::class,
]
```

then use as

```
CustomHelper::foo();
```

Comment: i am sorry if its so basic and so silly i want to do something like this syntax for example a user send me a variable called date so $date->convertdate(); and it convert dates for me so can it be the helper again ??

Comment: @Farshad yes you can use a helper or just use directly in view, as this is not effecting your real data.

Comment: thanks for your very complete and awesome answer i will try it and let u know if i got any problem which i think i should not :)

Answer (score 2):

create a function in a php file and add it in composer.json file inside "autoload" attribute, like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/CustomHelper.php"
    ]
}
```

and run `composer dump-autoload` command, Here - CustomHelper.php is the file, i want to autoload and their function can be used anywhere in your project

CustomHelper.php

```
<?php

  if (! function_exists('getOTP')) {
    function getOTP()
    {
        return str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, 4) - 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
  }

 ?>
```

now you can call getOTP() function anywhere in your project